# Best practice to publish src folder that contains esm modules

Tags: node.js, npm, bundler, publish, tree-shaking

Consider this package.json:

```
{
  "main": "./index.js",
  "name": "@myorg/foo",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist --delete-dir-on-start --source-maps inline --copy-files --no-copy-ignored",
    "check-release": "npm run release --dry-run",
    "postbuild": "cp package.json dist",
    "release": "npm run build && cd dist && npm publish"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what's the best practice in order to adjust it so it'll publish the src folder that contains ESM modules in a way that'll allow tree-shaking in the final app (CRA app).

Right now there are some issues with the above package.json:

- `npm publish` won't behave as I'd like to - you need to use `npm run release` instead and that's not good as other tooling will rely on `publish`
- To create the `dist` folder I'm using Babel but that doesn't feel right, is it better to use another tool instead to bundle it? My goal is the final app being able to use all imports easily (with no subpath exports, index, aliases, ...)

How would you adjust the above `package.json` to fullfill the above requirements?

Comment: You set ["type": "module"](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type), make sure the [exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points) field is set correctly, and then publish it like everything else. And then you read through [the docs for duel CJS/EMS releases](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#dual-commonjses-module-packages) if you need both. In fact, just give the entire https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html page a read, it covers everything you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the two points answered!

---

> `npm publish` won't behave as I'd like to... you need to use `npm run release` instead and that's not good as other tooling will rely on `publish`.

If you look below, you can see that Babel has been removed. Due to this, there is no need for your `release` script anymore.

You can just run the `publish` command when it is ready.

```
$ npm publish --access=public
```

Remember, this only works if you did the below!

---

> To create the dist folder I'm using Babel but that doesn't feel right, is it better to use another tool instead to bundle it? My goal is the final app being able to use all imports easily (with no subpath exports, index, aliases, ...).

You can follow a few steps to stop using Babel and use an alternative:

1. In your `package.json`, add the following key:

   ```json
   {
     "type": "module"
   }
   ```

   With this, also change `require()` to `import`, and `module.exports` to `export`. For example:

   ```js
   // Before...
   const foo = require("@myorg/foo");
   module.exports = { func };

   // After...
   import foo from "@myorg/foo";
   export { func };
   ```
2. Instead of importing and exporting everything from one file, you can do that in a simpler way in `package.json`. You need to just add something like below:

   ```json
   {
     "exports": {
       ".": "./dist/index.js",
       "./feature": "./dist/feature.js",
     }
   }
   ```

   For more information, [see the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points).
3. When someone downloads your module, they will import like this (like Firebase):

   ```js
   import index from "@myorg/foo"; // index.js
   import features from "@myorg/foo/features"; // features.js
   ```

---

Not sure if these fully answered your question, but they might give you a starting point!